# changing the size of AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask

Does anyone know how I may specify the size (number of threads) of `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` in android?

Answer (score 3):

The right answer is to create your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use that with `executeOnExecutor()`. That way, you do not affect any third-party code that may get messed up by a different `ThreadPoolExecutor` configuration.

While it is presently possible to call methods like [`setCorePoolSize()` on that `ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html#setCorePoolSize%28int%29) by downcasting the `Executor` to `ThreadPoolExecutor`, this is risky. Google -- or a manufacturer, or a ROM mod author -- could change the implementation of `THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` to be something else, causing your code to crash.